# Check if cookie has specific value to prevent duplicates

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm writing a code for a shopping cart. I need to check if the cookie already has de id of a selected item so that it won't duplicate it.

Code:

```
Dim cookie_carrito As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("CkEntregas")
        Dim i_docid As Integer = iddoc_print.Text


        If cookie_carrito IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim valor_galleta As String = cookie_carrito.Value
            Dim galleticas As String() = valor_galleta.Split(","c)

            For Each item In galleticas

                Dim id_documento = item

                If id_documento = i_docid Then
                    l_resultados_carrito.Text = "<div class='Col100'><div class='notificacionesCT'><i class='fa fa-bell fa-fw'></i> Este documento ya se encuentra en tu carrito de entregas.<a href='encriptar-documento.aspx?actid=2&docid=" & i_docid & "'><i class='fa fa-window-close fa-fw'></i></a></div></div>"
                Else

                    Dim hoy As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.ToUniversalTime.AddHours(-5)
                    Dim cookie_actual As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("CkEntregas")

                    Dim cookie_carrito_u As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("CkEntregas")
                    cookie_carrito_u.Value = i_docid & "," & cookie_actual.Value
                    cookie_carrito_u.Expires = hoy.AddHours(72)
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_carrito_u)
                    'resultados.Text = "Cookie actualizada: " & cookie_carrito_u.Value
                    l_resultados_carrito.Text = "<div class='Col100'><div class='notificacionesOK'><i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i> ¡Listo! El documento fue agregado con éxito al carrito de entregas.<a href='encriptar-documento.aspx?actid=2&docid=" & i_docid & "'><i class='fa fa-window-close fa-fw'></i></a></div></div>"

                    Exit For
                End If

            Next

        Else
            Dim hoy As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.ToUniversalTime.AddHours(-5)
            Dim cookie_carrito_n As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("CkEntregas")
            cookie_carrito_n.Value = i_docid
            cookie_carrito_n.Expires = hoy.AddHours(72)
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_carrito_n)
            'resultados.Text = "Cookie creada: " & cookie_carrito_n.Value
            l_resultados_carrito.Text = "<div class='Col100'><div class='notificacionesOK'><i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i> ¡Listo! El documento fue agregado con éxito al carrito de entregas.<a href='encriptar-documento.aspx?actid=2&docid=" & i_docid & "'><i class='fa fa-window-close fa-fw'></i></a></div></div>"
        End If
```

The logic that I'm using is to check each comma splitted value, so if that value is contained in the cookie items (list) it won't add it, but if the value is not there it will add it and break the loop.

It's not working, because if the first value in the cookie is different than the selected item, it will add it, but it may be in the second position of the list.

How can I check if a determined value is already in the cookie?

The cookie stores values in this format: 1,5,3,9,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it checking the value of the cookie as a String, using the string.Contains() method:

```
Dim cookie_carrito As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("CkEntregas")
        Dim i_docid As Integer = iddoc_print.Text


        If cookie_carrito IsNot Nothing Then

            Dim valor_galleta As String = cookie_carrito.Value
            Dim galleticas As String() = valor_galleta.Split(","c)

            If valor_galleta.Contains(i_docid) Then
                l_resultados_carrito.Text = "<div class='Col100'><div class='notificacionesCT'><i class='fa fa-bell fa-fw'></i> Este documento ya se encuentra en tu carrito de entregas.<a href='encriptar-documento.aspx?actid=2&docid=" & i_docid & "'><i class='fa fa-window-close fa-fw'></i></a></div></div>"
            Else
                Dim hoy As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.ToUniversalTime.AddHours(-5)
                Dim cookie_actual As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies("CkEntregas")

                Dim cookie_carrito_u As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("CkEntregas")
                cookie_carrito_u.Value = i_docid & "," & cookie_actual.Value
                cookie_carrito_u.Expires = hoy.AddHours(72)
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_carrito_u)
                l_resultados_carrito.Text = "<div class='Col100'><div class='notificacionesOK'><i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i> ¡Listo! El documento fue agregado con éxito al carrito de entregas.<a href='encriptar-documento.aspx?actid=2&docid=" & i_docid & "'><i class='fa fa-window-close fa-fw'></i></a></div></div>"

            End If

        Else
            Dim hoy As DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date.ToUniversalTime.AddHours(-5)
            Dim cookie_carrito_n As HttpCookie = New HttpCookie("CkEntregas")
            cookie_carrito_n.Value = i_docid
            cookie_carrito_n.Expires = hoy.AddHours(72)
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie_carrito_n)
            l_resultados_carrito.Text = "<div class='Col100'><div class='notificacionesOK'><i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i> ¡Listo! El documento fue agregado con éxito al carrito de entregas.<a href='encriptar-documento.aspx?actid=2&docid=" & i_docid & "'><i class='fa fa-window-close fa-fw'></i></a></div></div>"
        End If
```